# PHP Column count correct yet still getting "Column Count Doesn't Match Value Count At Row 1"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

Like the title says there are 13 columns being inserted into the database, and yet it says the following error when I try input values into all of the fields: Column Count Doesn't Match Value Count At Row 1

```
$insert = mysqli_query($con, 
"INSERT INTO Users 
(
username, 
email, 
password, 
entertainer, 
artist, 
musician, 
twitch, 
youtube, 
youtubeuser, 
website, 
bio, 
facebook, 
twitter
)
VALUES 
(
'{$_POST[u_username]}',
'{$_POST[u_email]}',
'{$_POST[u_password]}',
'{$_POST[u_entertainer]}',
'{$_POST[u_artist]}', 
'{$_POST[u_musician]}', 
'{$_POST[u_twitch]}', 
'{$_POST[u_youtube]}', 
'{$_POST[u_youtubeuser]}', 
'{$_POST[u_website]}', 
'{$_POST[u_bio]}, 
'{$_POST[u_facebook]}', 
'{$_POST[u_twitter]}
)");
```

I've spaced out the code to make it easier to read, any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this is the query which gives this error?

Comment: For debugging purposes only... $query = "INSERT..."; echo $query; And an odd number of inverted commas is, well, odd.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: @MarcB This isn't for public use, just my own little database mostly for testing but cheers for the concern.

Comment: you're missing a ' in the last $_POST[u_twitter] and u_bio mate

Comment: @OliverMGrech thanks, I feel stupid for not noticing, swear I've been staring at it for an hour and they all looked correct to me

Comment: do not feel stupid, learn from it :) I tell my employees that when they spend more then an hour on a problem, leave it for later and have a break. You'll be amazed on how fast you'll solve it when you are relaxed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typos:

```
'{$_POST[u_bio]},    <---missing closing '
'{$_POST[u_facebook]}', 
'{$_POST[u_twitter]} <---another missing closing '
)");
```

So, yes. you are **NOT** sending over the same number of columns v.s. values.